# Shopify Collection - Return string based on Collection Title

Tags: html, collections, shopify, liquid

I am trying to add some text based off text contained within the Title of a collection and have this so far. Nothing is being output to the page but I'm struggling to see a reason why - having tried different strings in the conditions.

I have tried with and with collection.title and {{collection.title}} and various strings/parts of the string that are in the collections title.

```html
{% if collection.title contains 'text' %}
  <div class="lfl_text"><p>output this text</p>
      {% endif %}
  </div>
```

I'm fairly new to liquid so go easy on me!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on a collection page, you can get the collection title with `{{ collection.title }}`.

```
<div class="lfl_text">
  <p>{{ collection.title }}</p>
</div>
```

If you want to do something with the collection title text, have a play with string filters >> https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/string-filters